# Issue with PhoneGap Network Information Plugin on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a PhoneGap app, and have an issue with installing one particular module, "Network Information" (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information). `phonegap -v` shows I'm running version 5.3.7

All other plugins seem to be working fine. This is an issue in the application I'm working on but I've also managed to reproduce it in a new application: The only two files I've changed are index.html and js/index.js in this example, and there is no js/cordova.js file, which is automatically included ([Cordova Network and Camera API returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960901/cordova-network-and-camera-api-returns-undefined))

I've created the app using the following commands:

```
phonegap create ios-test
cd ios-test
phonegap cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
phonegap cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

The output of phonegap cordova plugin list is:

```
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
```

Based on a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28332230) I've wrapped this in a setTimeout() call, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is the HTML (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JS:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        navigator.notification.alert('Test', null, 'Test', 'OK');

        setTimeout(function() {
            navigator.notification.alert('Debug', null, 'Checking connection', 'OK');

            if (navigator.connection == undefined) {
                navigator.notification.alert('navigator.connection is undefined', null, 'Error', 'OK');
                return;
            }

            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            navigator.notification.alert('Network Status', null, 'Connection type: ' + states[networkState], 'OK');
        }, 5000);
    }
};
```

Upon running the code with `phonegap serve` and the Developer app on my iPhone, I get the Debug alert then see "navigator.connection is undefined".

---

I've also tried to build for iOS:

```
phonegap platform add ios

Adding ios project...
Running command: /Users/James/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.9.2/package/bin/create /Web/ios-test/platforms/ios com.phonegap.helloworld "Hello World" --cli
iOS project created with cordova-ios@3.9.2
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Installing to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" for ios
```

This creates a `platforms/ios` folder, but I still have the same issue.

---

I've also tried:

- Checking ARC is enabled, [iOS8 phonegap cordova network-information app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790729/ios8-phonegap-cordova-network-information-app-crashes)
- Adding the following to `config.xml` [Check internet connection on iOS app with Cordova Phonegap 3.3.0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682388/check-internet-connection-on-ios-app-with-cordova-phonegap-3-3-0-not-working/20685331#20685331):

> ```
> <feature name="NetworkStatus">
>   <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
> </feature>
> ```

- Using `navigator.network.connection.type` instead, [Check internet connection on iOS app with Cordova Phonegap 3.3.0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682388/check-internet-connection-on-ios-app-with-cordova-phonegap-3-3-0-not-working/20685331#)
- Checking AudioToolbox.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework are both added: [Cordova Network Plugin does not build on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472172/cordova-network-plugin-does-not-build-on-ios)

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the `this` context correctly. This is a common mistake. The Javascript `this` does NOT work like the Java `this`.

The reason it does not work is because the `this` gets resolved at **run-time**, not *assemble-time* (or *compile-time*). When the event fires, `this` resolves to the the global `this` because your `app` object is now out of scope. The event fires *outside* of your `app` object.

A quick fix would be to do `app.onDeviceReady` instead of <s>`this.onDeviceReady`</s>  You can test this by making your`onDeviceReady()` a global function and leaving the `this` in place.

OHH, and that `setTimeout()` answer is someone that does not know they need to wait for the `deviceready` event. Bad code and bad advice abound in the Javascript world.

These videos should help. – Best of Luck.

- [Context in JavaScript - 1/4 - Purpose and Problems with JavaScript's "This"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=su-SdgebJCE)
- [Context in JavaScript - 2/4 - How JavaScript Decides What "This" Actually Is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ_YD4Ljbqc)
- [Context in JavaScript - 3/4 - "This" May Not Be What You Expected & How to Fix It](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNqoehDEZ3E)
- [Context in JavaScript - 4/4 - Mastering "This:" Additional Techniques & Future Support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ4__W9nELc)

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's really useful! With the following, I still get 'network.connection is undefined': https://gist.github.com/jfi/14fcff97e8c3c98259aa

Comment: I don't do CLi, althought I should. I've been using *[Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)*. On not getting network access, if you are using iOS9, then you need to apply `CSP` and `ATS`. The `whitelist` plugin has been dropped as of a few days ago. I have not had time to fix this post. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md). Again, the `whitelist` plugin only no longer applies to iOS9, `CSP` and `ATS` are still valid. Best of Luck

Comment: @JamesI, See my comments to your original post. Your `config.xml` has issues.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I did manage to get this working with PhoneGap Build using the following:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="1.0.1" />

<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

No luck with CLI though, so leaving this unanswered as that was the original question (and would still be easier to get that working).

Comment: `<feature (...)>` is deprecated. See [#12](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#012) of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) Your plugin will fail fail, is not now, in the future, See blog ["PhoneGap 5.2.0 Now Available on Build"](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/23/phonegap_520_now_on_build/). QUOTE: *"Also make sure your third party plugins all are up-to-date, and that your core plugins are being sourced from NPM, like so:"*