# phonegap cordova gelocation not showing out on phone

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```js
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);
 
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
draggable: true,
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

 });
  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: "My Location"
            });

        });
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Geo Location</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1oJGDZP2lM3c1dnPBmAbPBOb_Rh4u8n0&sensor=true"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 asd

<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this two file the google map is not appearing in my phone I dont know why but when run this in the web browser it work I had also install the cordova geolocation plugin and add permission but still unable to get it work can anyone of you help me out?

Comment: You have to whitelisten external urls, read the cordova docs -> Whitelist plugin.

Comment: ya whitelist is added

Comment: can i ask how to write the external url?

Answer (score 0):

@user3711175,
you have several issues. @Joerg is correct. You will need to use the `whitelist` system. <s>You have two (2) issues.</s>

**UPDATE - 2015-12-23**: I misread the code. #1 does not apply

<s>###1. You are using the `this` in the wrong context in your</s>

`document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);`

You want to write `app.onDeviceReady`, like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
```

When your EventListener finally fires, it is no longer in the context of you `app` Object. It is now global. For details, See this SO post

- [Issue with PhoneGap Network Information Plugin on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647478/issue-with-phonegap-network-information-plugin-on-ios/33717703#33717703)

#### 2. You need to apply the `whitelist` system

This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

The following need to be added to the `whitelist` for *Google map production*.

The following domains are required for Google Maps.

- maps.googleapis.com
- mt0.googleapis.com mt1.googleapis.com
- fonts.googleapis.com
- csi.gstatic.com
- maps.gstatic.com

Wild cards (`*`) are available. Read the documentation.